# Kafka API: java.io.IOException: Can't resolve address: xxx.x.x.xx:9091

Tags: java, scala, apache-kafka

I am trying to send messages to Kafka which is installed in a Ubuntu VM.

There are 3 Kafka brokers which have been started in the VM and a Consumer listening on the Topic also in the VM. All this works fine.

In Intellij on Windows 7 I have written a small demo app for a KafkaProducer,

```
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerRecord;

import java.util.Properties;

public class KafkaProducerApp {

    public static void main(String [] args){

        // Create a properties dictionary for the required/optional Producer config settings:
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9091,localhost:9092");
        props.put("key.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");
        props.put("value.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");
        //--> props.put("config.setting", "value");
        //:: http://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html#producerconfigs

        System.out.println("program start");

        KafkaProducer<String, String> myProducer = new KafkaProducer<String, String>(props);

        try{
            for (int i = 0; i < 150; i++){
                myProducer.send(new ProducerRecord<String, String>("my-topic", Integer.toString(i), "MyMessage: " + Integer.toString(i)));
            }
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally{
            System.out.println("program close");
            myProducer.close();
        }

        System.out.println("program end");

    }

}
```

When I try running the code though it doesnt connect to the Message Brokers - instead seems to go into an infinite loop and only stops when I click on Stop. Below is the output from the Intellij Terminal window. I get the

> Connection Refused

exception below. Anyone have any ideas how I can solve this ?

Is there anyway I can check the connection from Windows to the Ubuntu VM port number shown ? I am wondering if there is potentially a firewall issue preventing the connection.

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\bin\java" -Dorg.slf4j.simpleLogger.defaultLogLevel=DEBUG "-javaagent:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2017.1.3\lib\idea_rt.jar=62649:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2017.1.3\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\charsets.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\deploy.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\ext\access-bridge-64.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\ext\cldrdata.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\ext\dnsns.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\ext\jaccess.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\ext\jfxrt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\ext\localedata.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\ext\nashorn.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\ext\sunec.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\ext\sunjce_provider.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\ext\sunmscapi.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\ext\sunpkcs11.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\ext\zipfs.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\javaws.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\jce.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\jfr.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\jfxswt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\jsse.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\management-agent.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\plugin.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\resources.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\rt.jar;C:\Dev\kafka-poc\target\classes;C:\Users\rstannard\.m2\repository\org\apache\kafka\kafka-clients\0.10.2.1\kafka-clients-0.10.2.1.jar;C:\Users\rstannard\.m2\repository\net\jpountz\lz4\lz4\1.3.0\lz4-1.3.0.jar;C:\Users\rstannard\.m2\repository\org\xerial\snappy\snappy-java\1.1.2.6\snappy-java-1.1.2.6.jar;C:\Users\rstannard\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\slf4j-api\1.7.21\slf4j-api-1.7.21.jar;C:\Users\rstannard\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\slf4j-simple\1.7.21\slf4j-simple-1.7.21.jar" com.riskcare.kafkapoc.KafkaProducerApp
program start
[main] INFO org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerConfig - ProducerConfig values: 
    acks = 1
    batch.size = 16384
    block.on.buffer.full = false
    bootstrap.servers = [localhost:9091, localhost:9092]
    buffer.memory = 33554432
    client.id = 
    compression.type = none
    connections.max.idle.ms = 540000
    interceptor.classes = null
    key.serializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
    linger.ms = 0
    max.block.ms = 60000
    max.in.flight.requests.per.connection = 5
    max.request.size = 1048576
    metadata.fetch.timeout.ms = 60000
    metadata.max.age.ms = 300000
    metric.reporters = []
    metrics.num.samples = 2
    metrics.sample.window.ms = 30000
    partitioner.class = class org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.DefaultPartitioner
    receive.buffer.bytes = 32768
    reconnect.backoff.ms = 50
    request.timeout.ms = 30000
    retries = 0
    retry.backoff.ms = 100
    sasl.jaas.config = null
    sasl.kerberos.kinit.cmd = /usr/bin/kinit
    sasl.kerberos.min.time.before.relogin = 60000
    sasl.kerberos.service.name = null
    sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.jitter = 0.05
    sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.window.factor = 0.8
    sasl.mechanism = GSSAPI
    security.protocol = PLAINTEXT
    send.buffer.bytes = 131072
    ssl.cipher.suites = null
    ssl.enabled.protocols = [TLSv1.2, TLSv1.1, TLSv1]
    ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm = null
    ssl.key.password = null
    ssl.keymanager.algorithm = SunX509
    ssl.keystore.location = null
    ssl.keystore.password = null
    ssl.keystore.type = JKS
    ssl.protocol = TLS
    ssl.provider = null
    ssl.secure.random.implementation = null
    ssl.trustmanager.algorithm = PKIX
    ssl.truststore.location = null
    ssl.truststore.password = null
    ssl.truststore.type = JKS
    timeout.ms = 30000
    value.serializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer

[main] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics - Added sensor with name bufferpool-wait-time
[main] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics - Added sensor with name buffer-exhausted-records
[main] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.Metadata - Updated cluster metadata version 1 to Cluster(id = null, nodes = [localhost:9092 (id: -2 rack: null), localhost:9091 (id: -1 rack: null)], partitions = [])
[main] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics - Added sensor with name connections-closed:
[main] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics - Added sensor with name connections-created:
[main] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics - Added sensor with name bytes-sent-received:
[main] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics - Added sensor with name bytes-sent:
[main] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics - Added sensor with name bytes-received:
[main] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics - Added sensor with name select-time:
[main] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics - Added sensor with name io-time:
[main] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics - Added sensor with name batch-size
[main] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics - Added sensor with name compression-rate
[main] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics - Added sensor with name queue-time
[main] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics - Added sensor with name request-time
[main] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics - Added sensor with name produce-throttle-time
[main] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics - Added sensor with name records-per-request
[main] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics - Added sensor with name record-retries
[main] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics - Added sensor with name errors
[main] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics - Added sensor with name record-size-max
[kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender - Starting Kafka producer I/O thread.
[main] INFO org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser - Kafka version : 0.10.2.1
[main] INFO org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser - Kafka commitId : e89bffd6b2eff799
[main] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer - Kafka producer started
[kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - Initialize connection to node -1 for sending metadata request
[kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - Initiating connection to node -1 at localhost:9091.
[kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics - Added sensor with name node--1.bytes-sent
[kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics - Added sensor with name node--1.bytes-received
[kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics - Added sensor with name node--1.latency
[kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector - Connection with localhost/127.0.0.1 disconnected
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: no further information
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:717)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.PlaintextTransportLayer.finishConnect(PlaintextTransportLayer.java:51)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.KafkaChannel.finishConnect(KafkaChannel.java:81)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.pollSelectionKeys(Selector.java:335)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.poll(Selector.java:303)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.poll(NetworkClient.java:349)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.run(Sender.java:225)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.run(Sender.java:126)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
[kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - Node -1 disconnected.
[kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - Initialize connection to node -2 for sending metadata request
[kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - Initiating connection to node -2 at localhost:9092.
[kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics - Added sensor with name node--2.bytes-sent
[kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics - Added sensor with name node--2.bytes-received
[kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics - Added sensor with name node--2.latency
[kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector - Connection with localhost/127.0.0.1 disconnected
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: no further information
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:717)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.PlaintextTransportLayer.finishConnect(PlaintextTransportLayer.java:51)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.KafkaChannel.finishConnect(KafkaChannel.java:81)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.pollSelectionKeys(Selector.java:335)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.poll(Selector.java:303)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.poll(NetworkClient.java:349)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.run(Sender.java:225)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.run(Sender.java:126)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
[kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - Node -2 disconnected.
[kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - Initialize connection to node -1 for sending metadata request
[kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - Initiating connection to node -1 at localhost:9091.

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Below is some output from Ubuntu

[image]

---

Update to answer from ppatierno 
(I cant add images to comments so adding an update here instead)

Thank you for your comment. Below is an image from,
1/ my Windows Terminal using Telnet to try and connect to my VM session
2/ a screenshot from my Ubuntu VM session showing the ports open on Localhost 127.0.0.1.
3/ ipconfig showing my ip address from my Host
4/ ifconfig showing ip address from my Ubuntu VM (Guest).

Am I missing anything ?

[image]

[image]

### UPDATE

I've managed to get the IP and Port recognised, the below link helped me to configure my VM,

https://www.howtogeek.com/122641/how-to-forward-ports-to-a-virtual-machine-and-use-it-as-a-server/

but now I am running into another issue when I try to run my Java Producer application. The logs seem to suggest that its able to recognise the 3-Brokers but for some reason the program is unable to connect with a Broker.

> [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] DEBUG
>   org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - Initialize connection to node
>   -1 for sending metadata request [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - Initiating
>   connection to node -1 at 192.168.56.101:9091.
>   [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] DEBUG
>   org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics - Added sensor with name
>   node--1.bytes-sent [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] DEBUG
>   org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics - Added sensor with name
>   node--1.bytes-received [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1]
>   DEBUG org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics - Added sensor with name
>   node--1.latency [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] DEBUG
>   org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector - Created socket with
>   SO_RCVBUF = 32768, SO_SNDBUF = 131072, SO_TIMEOUT = 0 to node -1
>   [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] DEBUG
>   org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - Completed connection to node
>   -1.  Fetching API versions. [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - Initiating
>   API versions fetch from node -1. [kafka-producer-network-thread |
>   producer-1] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - Recorded
>   API versions for node -1: (Produce(0): 0 to 2 [usable: 2], Fetch(1): 0
>   to 3 [usable: 3], Offsets(2): 0 to 1 [usable: 1], Metadata(3): 0 to 2
>   [usable: 2], LeaderAndIsr(4): 0 [usable: 0], StopReplica(5): 0
>   [usable: 0], UpdateMetadata(6): 0 to 3 [usable: 3],
>   ControlledShutdown(7): 1 [usable: 1], OffsetCommit(8): 0 to 2 [usable:
>   2], OffsetFetch(9): 0 to 2 [usable: 2], GroupCoordinator(10): 0
>   [usable: 0], JoinGroup(11): 0 to 1 [usable: 1], Heartbeat(12): 0
>   [usable: 0], LeaveGroup(13): 0 [usable: 0], SyncGroup(14): 0 [usable:
>   0], DescribeGroups(15): 0 [usable: 0], ListGroups(16): 0 [usable: 0],
>   SaslHandshake(17): 0 [usable: 0], ApiVersions(18): 0 [usable: 0],
>   CreateTopics(19): 0 to 1 [usable: 1], DeleteTopics(20): 0 [usable: 0])
>   [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] DEBUG
>   org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - Sending metadata request
>   (type=MetadataRequest, topics=my-topic) to node -1
>   [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] DEBUG
>   org.apache.kafka.clients.Metadata - Updated cluster metadata version 2
>   to Cluster(id = QZEI79XCTmC8qJ48K1JwLw, nodes =
>   [C0287.VM.xxxxxxxx.com:9092 (id: 2 rack: null),
>   C0287.VM.xxxxxxxx.com:9090 (id: 0 rack: null),
>   C0287.VM.xxxxxxxx.com:9091 (id: 1 rack: null)], partitions =
>   [Partition(topic = my-topic, partition = 0, leader = 1, replicas =
>   [0,1,2], isr = [1,2,0]), Partition(topic = my-topic, partition = 1,
>   leader = 2, replicas = [0,1,2], isr = [2,0,1]), Partition(topic =
>   my-topic, partition = 2, leader = 0, replicas = [0,1,2], isr =
>   [0,1,2])]) [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] DEBUG
>   org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - Initiating connection to node
>   0 at C0287.VM.xxxxxxxx.com:9090. program close [main] INFO
>   org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer - Closing the Kafka
>   producer with timeoutMillis = 9223372036854775807 ms.
>   [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] DEBUG
>   org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - Error connecting to node 0 at
>   C0287.VM.xxxxxxxx.com:9090: java.io.IOException: Can't resolve
>   address: C0287.VM.XXX.com:9090    at
>   org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.connect(Selector.java:182)
>     at
>   org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.initiateConnect(NetworkClient.java:629)
>     at
>   org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.ready(NetworkClient.java:186)
>     at
>   org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.run(Sender.java:184)
>     at
>   org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.run(Sender.java:126)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) Caused by:
>   java.nio.channels.UnresolvedAddressException  at
>   sun.nio.ch.Net.checkAddress(Net.java:101)     at
>   sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.connect(SocketChannelImpl.java:622)  at
>   org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.connect(Selector.java:179)
>     ... 5 more [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] DEBUG
>   org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender - Beginning
>   shutdown of Kafka producer I/O thread, sending remaining records.
>   [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] DEBUG
>   org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - Initiating connection to node
>   1 at C0287.VM.xxxxxxxx.com:9091. [kafka-producer-network-thread |
>   producer-1] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - Error
>   connecting to node 1 at C0287.VM.xxxxxxxx.com:9091:
>   java.io.IOException: Can't resolve address: C0287.VM.xxxxxxxx.com:9091

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try providing dns mapping in your host file on the host machine (windows host name file). You can find it under `System32/etc` folder.

Comment: yes that worked for me - thank you !  

In Windows => C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts file I added the mapping line entry  
"192.168.56.101  C0287.xx.xxxx.com"  

and then in the Java code changed the line as so,  
  
props.put("bootstrap.servers", "192.168.56.101:9090, 192.168.56.101:9091, 192.168.56.101:9092");  
  
Now when I run the Producer code I see the messages arriving in my Consumer in the VM.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure all three of your kafka brokers are configured with advertised listeners on an IP address and port that is reachable from your app running outside the VM.

See advertised.listeners broker parameter in the documentation here

https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#brokerconfigs

Comment: Thank you Hans. I think you're right. The problem I am haivng is not really about Kakfa but rather about my Java program (Windows-Host) being able to reach the IP/Port in my VM (Guest). I am not sure how to configure this so may submit a separate question about this. I guess I could install Intellij inside my VM and then everything would work (or install Kafka on Windows) but I think I prefer to keep things self-contained in the VM as they currently are.

Comment: I've managed to get the IP and Port recognised, the below link helped me to configure my VM,  
https://www.howtogeek.com/122641/how-to-forward-ports-to-a-virtual-machine-and-use-it-as-a-server/

Answer (score 1):

From what you are saying it seems to me that the producer is running on the host and not inside the VM (as the consumer). You are trying to connect from the host using :

localhost:9091,localhost:9092

you should use the VM IP address or allowing the VM to share the host network.

Comment: robbie70 pay attention. You are trying to edit my answer instead of adding a comment and I'm rejecting that. Please add a comment.

Comment: ok no worries I've updated the Question. I wanted to edit your answer because I couldnt attach images to a Comment

Comment: what virtualization software are you using ?

Comment: I was unable to ping the Guest virtualbox session so I have followed the suggestions in this post.....

https://2buntu.com/articles/1513/accessing-your-virtualbox-guest-from-your-host-os/

now I am able to ping the virtualbox session from my Windows CMD prompt but I still cant telnet to the port. I am trying,
c:\dev>telnet 192.168.56.101 9091

I get the error message,
Connecting To 192.168.56.101...Could not open connection to the host, on port 9091: Connect failed

But I can execute the telnet command from my Ubuntu Virtualbox Terminal session and it works fine.

Comment: Maybe something related to a firewall on the VM ?

Comment: Kafka producer started........
.....................................
org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector - Connection with /192.168.56.101 disconnected
java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: no further information
 at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
 at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:717)
 at org.apache.kafka.common.network.PlaintextTransportLayer.finishConnect(PlaintextTransportLayer.java:51)
 at org.apache.kafka.common.network.KafkaChannel.finishConnect(KafkaChannel.java:81)
Process finished with exit code 1

Answer (score 1):

change your `conf/server.properties` file as follow :

```
listeners=PLAINTEXT://192.168.1.120:9092
```

or

```
listeners=PLAINTEXT://hostname:9092
```

or

```
listeners=PLAINTEXT://localhost:9092
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with Ubuntu 16.04 and Docker. For me the [solution from Sudhesh Rajan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44565296/4685471) above worked. In `/etc/hosts` I changed DNS mapping. Just make sure that you are not trying to map ports.